# CSS hover to list

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to make a hover effect on my lists, what I want to achieve, when I hover to list it will only show it's own content. The issue is it shows all the other list when hover to single list. I'm using sass

JsFiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/PenAndPapers/f5qps3eu/

```
#ssb-container {
    li {
      cursor: pointer;
      &:hover {
        > p {
           a {
            margin-right: 75px;
          }
        }
      }
      p {
          a {
          margin-right: -125px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is currently unclear what your issue is. Please can you provide full code (including HTML) which will allow us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: can you fiddle here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/PenAndPapers/f5qps3eu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform` instead

```
  ul > li:hover {
    transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
```

Stack snippet

```css
#ssb-container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: -90px;
}

ul>li:hover {
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="ssb-container" class="ssb-btns-right" style="z-index: 1;">
  <ul class="ssb-dark-hover">
    <li id="ssb-btn-0">
      <p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Live Chat</a>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li id="ssb-btn-1">
      <p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-volume-control-phone"></i> We'll contact you</a>
      </p>
    </li>
    <li id="ssb-btn-2">
      <p>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact Us</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @LGSon